# Conflict between Nvidia Grid K2 & integrated graphics on Supermicro VDI?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, supermicro, graphics-processing-unit, remote-desktop

My office has a Supermicro SYS-1027GR-TR2-2NVK2 VDI server with dual Nvidia GRID K2 cards running Windows Server 2012 R2 & RemoteFX. We are an architectural firm and use 3D graphics software. Users RDP into Hyper-V Virtual Machines with Windows 8.1 Enterprise installed. Nvidia drivers on the server are up to date. Server shows Driver Model WDDM 1.3 as should be. The Matrox driver model is WDDM 1.2 On the virtual machines however, DxDiag shows Driver Model WDDM 1.2 and performance isn't good.

I have seen evidence here and elsewhere of a possible conflict between the GRID cards and the Matrox Nuvoton g200ew integrated graphics on the server. We tried disabling onboard graphics in BIOS which resulted in a hang on boot. Also disabling integrated graphics kills IPMI.

How do I get RemoteFX Graphics Driver on the VMs to see the right graphics card ? Assuming of course that's the reason the Driver model is appearing as 1.2 instead of 1.3. The Matrox does not appear in the list on the Hyper-V RemoteFX Manager.

Comment: Page 4 of the VDI licensing FAQ [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/9/1/591484C6-D5D4-4425-B0E6-38DCC30F6364/201003_Licensing-Windows-for-virtua-desktop-infrastructure-with-VDA.pdf) under : How do the new VDI Suites change the offering with Citrix? Says "Microsoft and Citrix have been partners for 20+ years, and have a joint go-to-market strategy around VDI." So the answer to my question is: Use XenDesktop & XenServer because RemoteFX will not support real graphics EVER. That market was handed over to Citrix with a bow on it, period.